# FullCalendar.js - Is there a view view with time on the x-axis and dates on the y-axis

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, custom-view, fullcalendar-5

I am using fullcalendar.js for a client and there is no builtin view to do something like this:
[fullcalendar-custom-view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zeXcx.jpg)

Is there any way to get something like this? Alternatives to fullcalendar or a custom view?

Comment: No there's no built in support for that.

Comment: P.s. see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/custom-view-with-js for initial guidance if you wanted to try and build it yourself, although I suspect it's not a simple task